# MVC 5: DropDown value as parameter to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a simple form with a dropdown and a submit button.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList(
        "Roles",
        new SelectList(new List<string> { "User", "Manager", "Chuck Norris" }),
        new { id = "role", name="role" })

    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string role) <-- role is null when clicking submit
{
}
```

I was kinda hoping the value from the dropdown would automatically be injected as parameter of my controller method, but this is not the case. Am I missing something or is it simply not possible to do it like this?

Comment: Your generating a `<select>` with `name="Roles"` but your parameter is named `role` (not plural). Change one or the other. (attempting to use `name = "role"` is ignored by the method - fortunately)

Comment: What is the resulting HTML that this creates?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generating a `<select>` element with `name="Roles"` but the parameter of your method is named `role` (not plural). You need to change one or the other so that they match (note that the `DefaulModelBinder` is not case sensitive, so the parameter can be `roles` or `ROleS`)`

Note that setting `new { name = "role" }` does not change the `name` attribute generated by the `HtmlHelper` method. It should also not be necessary to use `name { id = "role" }` - the method already generates `id="Roles"` so if you are referencing the element using javascript/jquery, then just use `$(#Roles')` as the selector

Answer (score 0):

Change `role` to `Roles` like the code below

```
public ActionResult Index(string role)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Index(string Roles)
```

now it will work